# Switched-mode power supply differential vs single-ended output filter

Tags: filter, passive-filter

These two filters (borrowed from [here](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/understanding-and-designing-differential-filters-for-communications-systems.html)) are mathematically equivalent.

[image: Differential vs. single-ended filter]

Passive output filters for class D amplifiers or phase-shifted full bridge converters are normally LC filters. I've seen both in different products over the years. Does it really matter if the implementation of these filters is single-ended or differential? Is there any advantage of one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Class D amplifiers should use normal-mode filters.

Note also, at high frequencies, a class D amplifier typically has a source impedance around zero ohms (i.e., Rds(on) of the bridge FETs), and if not a complete open circuit as load, then a high and typically inductive impedance (audio speakers, grid-tied inverters, etc.).  The prototype shown *will not suffice for this condition.*

The standard solution is to connect some damping resistance in parallel with the load, at high frequencies.  That is, use an R+C, where R is the characteristic impedance of the filter, and C such that the resistor becomes effective somewhat below Fc.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhfYo4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here, \$F_c = \frac{1}{2 \pi \sqrt{L C}}\$ and \$Z_0 = \sqrt{\frac{L}{C}}\$, and C2 = C4 should be more than 2.5 times C1 = C3, and R1 = R2 = Zo.

In a half-bridge circuit, only one (normal mode) filter is required, and that's that.

In a full-bridge circuit, in general, the timing of both legs will not exactly match (due to variations in propagation delays between components), therefore there is some common mode error between them.

Also, each bridge leg acts in the normal mode with respect to its supply nodes.  This is a more subtle observation concerning the switching loop, parasitic elements (of the filter and circuit layout), and EMI studies, which I will not go into detail about here, but suffice it to say there is justification to make this conclusion.

Additional CM filtering might be applied for EMI purposes, or the filter can be decomposed into DM and CM parts which might offer better control of the response, but a normal mode (i.e. two independent channels) filter design is certainly adequate.

Leaving one line shorted, and using that as a differential-only filter in a full-bridge complementary or PSPWM type amplifier, would be an unmitigated EMI disaster.  Quite literally: it would be lacking any mitigations whatsoever, having one leg of the inverter wired directly to the output.